# Units used for distance calculations by distance matrix tool of QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I can't seem to get the measure tool to match up with my distance matrix tool regardless of what measurements I use. There are conflicting answers on other posts about this question. Both of my layers are on WGS84

Comment: Please provide links to the "other posts about this question" that you mention so that we can try to improve any content in them that is "conflicting".

Comment: gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20291/what-are-the-units-of-the-distance-matrix-tool-results-in-qgis

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, most tools in a GIS will calculate distances in the units of the coordinate system. If they're WGS84, I suggest it's calculating distances in degrees which is nonsensical. I suggest projecting your data to a projected coordinate system which has units in metres or feet, depending on your local standard.

Comment: Thanks Fetzer. Can I ask why it is nonsensical? For example is there any way of converting degrees to KM ? Or are the 2 things relative to eachother at all?

Comment: One degree on west-east direction along the equator is 111 km while on the top of the North Pole the distance is 0 meters. Converters exist, for example https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml.

Comment: It's non-sensical because degree distances change on a sphere. Think of lines of longitude converging at the poles. The distances between them get smaller as you approach the poles. I won't answer your other questions in the comments as there are other posts on this site which answer them. I really do suggest you convert your data to a projected coordinate system first and try again.